# How to get a enum value from string in C#?

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum:

```
public enum baseKey : uint
{  
    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = 0x80000000,
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER = 0x80000001,
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002,
    HKEY_USERS = 0x80000003,
    HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG = 0x80000005
}
```

How can I, given the string `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, get a value `0x80000002` based on the enum?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

```
baseKey choice;
if (Enum.TryParse("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", out choice)) {
     uint value = (uint)choice;

     // `value` is what you're looking for

} else { /* error: the string was not an enum member */ }
```

Before .NET 4.5, you had to do the following, which is more error-prone and throws an exception when an invalid string is passed:

```
(uint)Enum.Parse(typeof(baseKey), "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE")
```

Comment: I always wonder why there is still no generic overload to Enum.Parse. It's long overdue.

Comment: Now there is the generic Enum.TryParse<TEnum>() method.

Answer (score 33):

Using Enum.TryParse you don't need the Exception handling:

```
baseKey e;

if ( Enum.TryParse(s, out e) )
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 24):

```
var value = (uint) Enum.Parse(typeof(baseKey), "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE");
```

Answer (score 17):

With some error handling...

```
uint key = 0;
string s = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE";
try
{
   key = (uint)Enum.Parse(typeof(baseKey), s);
}
catch(ArgumentException)
{
   //unknown string or s is null
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var value = (uint)Enum.Parse(typeof(basekey), "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", true);
```

This code snippet illustrates obtaining an enum value from a string. To convert from a string, you need to use the static `Enum.Parse()` method, which takes 3 parameters. The first is the type of enum you want to consider. The syntax is the keyword `typeof()` followed by the name of the enum class in brackets. The second parameter is the string to be converted, and the third parameter is a `bool` indicating whether you should ignore case while doing the conversion.

Finally, note that `Enum.Parse()` actually returns an object reference, that means you need to explicitly convert this to the required enum type(`string`,`int` etc).

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Alternate solution can be:

```
baseKey hKeyLocalMachine = baseKey.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
uint value = (uint)hKeyLocalMachine;
```

Or just:

```
uint value = (uint)baseKey.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
```

Comment: How exactly does that convert a string to the enum value?

Comment: Enums consist of two components: name and value. Let's say the name is "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" and the value is "0x80000002". Enum.Parse() method is useless in this case because you can cast the enum member to uint and get the value - 2147483650. Enum.Parse() of course gives the same result but instead of hardcoding a string as a parameter you can cast directly the enum variable you're working with.

Comment: You didn't convert the string `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"` to the value, as the OP asked, you converted the symbol `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` to the value. Wildly different beasts.