# Writing Enum List Values to Serial Port

Tags: c#, enums, serial-port

Is it possible to grab the value of an enum list item? I created an enum list in which each item is tied to a byte value.

```
public enum Items : byte
{
   Item1 = 0x00,
   Item2 = 0x01,
   Item3 = 0x02 .... 
}
```

My listbox is populated with these items and I am looking for a way to write the associated byte value if selected. Is there something similar to the example below that could work for such a task?

```
if(listbox.SelectedItem = Item1 .. 2 .. 3)
{
  // Write byte value of Item1 .. 2 .. 3 via serial port
}
```

Comment: Just cast selected item to `byte`: `port.Write((byte)listbox.SelectedItem);` (note, that this works if items in `ListBox` are enum members).

Comment: Thanks Dennis ... I tried using this approach but I got an error stating "cannot convert from 'byte' to 'string'. So I tried: port.Write(((byte)listbox.SelectedItem).ToString()) but then I got a "Specified cast is not valid" message.

Comment: @Nevets Dennis has the right idea, i've elaborated on it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dennis suggested, you just need to cast the `enum` to a `byte`. You then need to pass this in as a `byte[]` to `Write`:

```
port.Write(new [] { (byte) listBox.SelectedItem }, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks gleng. I tried using this approach but I got an error stating "cannot convert from 'byte' to 'string'. So then I tried: `port.Write(((byte)listbox.SelectedItem).ToString())` but then I got a "Specified cast is not valid" message.

Comment: Thanks againg gleng. I am able to compile and run the code now but I am still getting the "Specified cast is not valid" error. Does this have more to do with my enumeration list or with the way I am trying to access the byte data?

Comment: @Nevets Based on what you've said, your listBox.SelectedItem should be an `enum` of type `Items`. So it's likely this is not the case, which is causing your error.

Comment: For my listbox I load the enum values upon loading the form ... `private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)                 {                                                                   foreach(string cmd in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Items))                 {                                                    listbox.Items.Add(cmd);                                                               }                                                                  }`

Comment: So `SelectedItem` is of type `String`. You need to `Enum.TryParse` that to your `Items` enum then cast to a `byte` like i've done.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47053/discussion-between-nevets-and-gleng)

Comment: Would that look like Is it something like ... `byte enumValue = Enum.TryParse<Items>(listbox.SelectedItem.ToString(), (byte)listbox.SelectedItem)`?

Comment: @Nevets Look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578775/how-to-get-a-enum-value-from-string-in-c

Comment: That answered my last question. Thank you a million times!