# Find string in enum

Tags: c#, enums

Is there a way to find part of a string in an enum like this:

```
Status.Find("InStock");

public enum Status
{
    Unknown,
    InStock,
    InStockReserved,
    Taken,
    TakenReserved,
    Spent,
}
```

And then get the respective int values.
Like in the Find command for a List:

```
list.Find(x => x.Name.Contains("InStock")));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a enum value from string in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578775/how-to-get-a-enum-value-from-string-in-c)

Comment: What happens when more than one enum value is found - in your example 2 results are possible.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use enums like this. You can get the list of all names in the enum by calling `Enum.GetNames(typeof(Status))`, but you shouldn't really be using enums like this anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
var integers = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status))
                   .Cast<Status>()
                   .Where(status => status.ToString().Contains("InStock"))
                   .Select(status => (int) status);
```

Comment: `List.Find` would only return the first match but granted, this is probably what the OP wants. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Enum gives integer return value. So you have two possibilities out of many:

1. Match based on enum type variable only.

for example:

```
list.Find(x => (x.StockType == Stock.InStock));
```

2. Define a function that return corresponding string form:

   string ToEnumString(Stock stockType)
   {
       if(stockType == Stock.InStock)
           return  "InStock";

   ```
   // TODO: define other cases
   ```

   }